# Golang convert raw image []byte to image.Image

Tags: image, go

Suppose I have an 8-bit grayscale image like this:

```
var pixels []byte = ...
width := 100
height := 100
```

How do I convert that into something that implements [`image.Image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/) package has several implementations of the [`image.Image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) interface.

If you can find an implementation which models the pixels just as you have it, you don't need to do anything just use that implementation.

For example the `image` package has an [`image.Gray`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Gray) type which implements `image.Image` and it models the pixels with one byte being  an 8-bit grayscale color.

So if you have exactly this, simply create a value of `image.Gray` and "tell it" to use your `pixels`:

```
pixels := make([]byte, 100*100) // slice of your gray pixels, size of 100x100

img := image.NewGray(image.Rect(0, 0, 100, 100))
img.Pix = pixels
```

**Note #1:**

Note that I used [`image.NewGray()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#NewGray) which returns you an initialized value of `image.Gray`, so we only needed to set / change the pixels slice. Since `image.Gray` is a struct with exported fields, we could also create it by manually initializing all its fields:

```
img := &image.Gray{Pix: pixels, Stride: 100, Rect: image.Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)}
```

(Note that I used a pointer because only `*image.Gray` implements `image.Image` as methods are defined with pointer receiver. `image.NewGray()` also returns a pointer.)

**Note #2:**

In our examples we set the `pixels` slice to be used by the image. The image is now bound to this slice. If we change anything in it, the pixel returned by `Image.At()` will also change (they use the same source). If you don't want this, you may copy the pixels to the `Gray.Pix` slice like this:

```
img := image.NewGray(image.Rect(0, 0, 100, 100))
copy(img.Pix, pixels)
```

Try these examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JUvZYVnYAB).